# Group of biholomorphic maps of polydisc fixing the origin is abelian

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show the polydisc and the unit open ball are not biholomorphic if the dimension is greater than one. I want to show that biholomorphisms of the polydisc fixing the origin is abelian whereas the group of such biholomorphisms for the unit open ball is $SU(N)$ which is clear. If they are biholomorphic, then one can reach the contradiction. I do not see how to show that biholomorphic maps of the polydisc is $U(N)$, which I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The group of biholomorphisms of the polydisc fixing the origin is not abelian. For example, consider the polydisc $\mathbb{D}\times\mathbb{D}$ and the two biholomorphisms $f(z_1, z_2) = (-z_1, z_2)$ and $g(z_1, z_2) = (z_2, z_1)$. Both $f$ and $g$ fix the origin, but $(f\circ g)(z_1, z_2) = (-z_2, z_1)$ while $(g\circ f)(z_1, z_2) = (z_2, -z_1)$ so $f\circ g \neq g\circ f$.