# Failure of Poincaré Theorem in higher dimensions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

The goal of exercise 1.1.16 in Huybrecht's *Complex Geometry* is to prove that the Poincaré Theorem fails in dimensions 2 and higher. It seeks to do so by proving that the polydisc $B:=B_{(1,1)}(0):=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb C^2:|z|<1 \text{ and } |w|<1\}$ and the unit disc $D:=\{a\in\mathbb C^2:\|a\|<1\}$ are not biholomorphic.

The exercise asks to prove the following, in exactly this order:

1. The two-dimensional unitary matrices form a subgroup of $\{f\in\mathrm{Aut}(D): f(0)=0\}$.
2. For every $a\in B$, there is $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(B)$ with $f(a)=0$.
3. The group $\{f\in\mathrm{Aut}(B): f(0)=0\}$ is Abelian.
4. $D$ and $B$ are not biholomorphic.

I was able to prove 1., 2. and, if I assume that 3. holds, also 4. However, I have difficulties to prove that 3. is true. Well, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2226225/730592), point 3. is actually incorrect, so the above exercise is false the way it is stated.

Since I already thought quite a lot about this exercise (particularly the wrong point 3...), I would really like to make this exercise work somehow. This is why I am wondering if point 3. can somehow be put into a correct form to still deduce point 4. from it, for instance by considering some particular subgroup of $\{f\in\mathrm{Aut}(D): f(0)=0\}$?

Comment: See exercise 1 from this takehome exam:
https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~caval101/homepage/Teaching_files/Exam2.pdf

Comment: This will be discussed in pretty much any textbook on several CVs.

Comment: If you're looking for a "group" proof of the result, you can do it a follows: $1$ can be strengthened to an equality between the two groups, while $3$ (where I'm guessing you meant to write $\text{Aut}(B)$) can be modified to $\{f\in \text{Aut}(B):f(0)=0\}\simeq \mathbb{T}^2\rtimes S_2$ (where $S_2$ is the permutation group). The two Lie groups have different dimension, hence we are done.

Comment: @Pelota Thanks. I have difficulties to prove equality in 1. Any hint?

Comment: Take $f$ as in 1. Since it's an automorphism, $Jf(0)$ is invertible and by Schwartz's lemma $\|Jf(0)\|\le 1$ . Applying Schwarz to the inverse we get $\|Jf(0)\|=1$. Now precompose $f$ with $Jf^{-1}$. You get a map $g:D\to D$, $g(0)=0, g'(0)=I$. By Cartan's uniqueness, $g(z)=z$ and we are done (now you just need to prove that the only linear automorphisms are the unitary maps). To prove Cartan's uniqueness, extract via Montel a converging subsequence from $\{g,g\circ g,\dots\}$ and call the limit h. Then $h(g)=g(h)=h$, which implies $h=\text{Id}$.